# Tumblr theme next + previous page visibility

Tags: paging, tumblr

On the paging part of creating a tumblr theme, I wanted to put a previous and a next button that is somewhat **disabled** when there are no previous and next pages available. The obvious available options only solves the problem if there is a next and previous page.

```
{block:PreviousPage}
  <a href="{PreviousPage}" title='View newer posts'>
    <input type='button' value='' class='pager pager_prev'/>
  </a>
{/block:PreviousPage}
...
```

If I'm on page 1, only the next button shows up (and ergo only the previous button on the last page). How will I be able to place the next+previous buttons in disabled states? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

And yes, I am answering my own question. After some decisions, I ended up using jQuery to check if the button exists and if not, append it as a child to some `td` or `div`. Well, this is not the perfect way to do it but I guess this makes sense on a count or two so I'm implementing this as of the moment.

If I'm on page 1, logically, I'll check if the previous button exists:

```
if($("input.previous_button").size()==0){
$("div.previous_button_box").html("<input type='button' class='pager pager-prev' ...
...
```

the same goes if I'm on the last page.